# Is "augmented with" or "augmented by" preferable?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, by-with

Which is the preferred preposition to use after the word "augmented", as in the sentence "A is augmented with/by B"? Does this depend on context?

For concreteness, I am interested in mathematical usage, as in the "The set is augmented with redundant vectors for greater numerical robustness".

Comment: I very much doubt I would notice one way or another if just reading a text that used either version. But thinking about it more consciously, I’m fairly sure that I would use _by_ only if the things augmenting were actually the real agent (i.e., the subject if the sentence is turned from active into passive); otherwise, I’d use _with_. In other words, “The set is augmented by redundant vectors” = “Redundant vectors augment the set”, but “The set is augmented with redundant vectors” = “I/we/someone augmented the set with/using redundant vectors”. Not sure if that’s just me overthinking, though.

Comment: That's quite similar to the intuition I have myself.

Comment: _Augmented by_ is part of a passive verb phrase; _augmented with_ is part of a predicate adjective verb phrase.

Comment: ***by*** appears to be the  more common preposition: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=augmented+by%2C+augmented+with+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caugmented%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caugmented%20with%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'd handle it this way:  A is augmented with noun B.  A is augmented by the addition of noun B.  But I do not have any justification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usage "A is augmented **by** B" indicates that B is the implied subject in the passive-voice construction "A is augmented". That is, B is doing the augmentation: "B augments A".

The usage "A is augmented **with** B" implies that B is what A is augmented with, by an *unspecified* subject. This is a predicate adjective verb phrase.

Thus, one could write  "The fruit salad is augmented **with** papaya **by** Sofia", meaning "Sofia augments the fruit salad with papaya".

In many cases, one could appeal to either of the two constructions - the difference is the sense of agency attributed to B.

Comment: I like Patrick Sanan's answer.  He provides an explanation for at least part of my earlier comment.  Another couple of examples:  Sweat tea is tea augmented by the addition of sugar.  Sweat tea is augmented with sugar.